# Which verse mentions "Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God."?

Tags: verse-identification

It is written: 'Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.'

Which verse mentions this?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't do verse search questions. This would've been really easy for you to find our by yourself, just search for it in Google or any other search engine!

Comment: Sure curiousdannii, but look what a great answer I got from GratefulDisciple. Curiously, you may have missed the significance of it. Jesus told the Pharisees: Moses wrote of Me.

Comment: @TonyChan If you want to ask about the deeper significance of texts, that's what our sister site [hermeneutics.se] is for! If you haven't visited there, make sure you take a look! :)

Comment: @TonyChan Ha, you escaped our human-powered bad question detector with a good answer.  Good for you! But don't make a habit of it.  Please ask questions about Christianity here, not just where to find something in the Bible.   If you were reading this in the Gospel and saw where Jesus said it and were wondering where "It is written", then that might have been an acceptable question; rather than being a "where to find it in the Bible" it's "what was Jesus talking about".

Comment: @curiousdannii, Peter Turner, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Many bible have cross-references, so that could also help answer future questions of this nature. Also, entering the phrase in a search-engine of choice can also help, if cross-references are not there. The first hit I got from searching the phrase was indeed Deut. 8:3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in [Deut 8:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+8&version=ESV), part of an extremely important and the last sermon Moses gave to the 2nd generation of Israelites while they were camping on the Plains of Moab before entering Canaan.  The main theme was reminding them of the importance to follow God's commandments so they would prosper in the promised land.  Otherwise they could end up like the 1st generation after Exodus whom God punished to die in the wilderness (except Caleb and Joshua).  Even God didn't allow Moses to enter Canaan.

The New Testament recorded Jesus quoting Deut 8:3 in response to the temptation of the devil while Jesus was fasting 40 days in the wilderness, similar to how the 1st generation was tested in the wilderness for 40 years.  But unlike the Israelites, Jesus succeeded.  Two passages recorded the quote:

- [Matt 4:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+4%3A1-11&version=ESV)
- [Luke 4:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+4%3A1-13&version=ESV)

Comment: This is a great reply to my question. If only I can only give you a million points. God bless you.

Comment: @TonyChan I'm glad I could help.  Welcome to C.SE!  You can click the "checkmark" to accept the answer, and once you gain 15 reputation points, you can also upvote the answer.  Looking forward for more of your contribution.

Comment: Done. Not only you answered my question technically, you also have shown me its significance.